# HTML Print Page Fitting

Tags: c#, html, printing, formatting

I have some HTML files that need to be printed out, but they are 2 pages long. I need them to be 1 page long and I don't want to have to fiddle with the HTML code endlessly to shrink it just a tiny bit. I know each HTML file can be opened and zoom resized in any HTML reader and then printed out and the problem is solved, however there are... A LOT of files and having to manually open each file, resizing it and then printing out each one individually isn't really a good solution for me. More HTML files will be generated.

If I could create a quick little application that takes an HTML file and shrinks the file down from 2 pages to 1 page ( will always be 2 pages ) or if there is some way to programmatically do a 'print to fit page' function? I can't find anything in this regards to print functions in default C# libraries yet.

Comment: You can provide an alternate CSS style that is for printing only that shrinks font sizes, changes margins, etc to make it fit.  Then it would display as you want and print in a way that will make it fit.

Comment: I am not familiar with 'CSS style' what exactly do you mean by this? Also, this seems like an eligable answer, you can re post this as an answer rather than a comment if you would like.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thank you John, I will keep this in mind and I will not include tags in my titles from now on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good tutorial that walks through what I was talking about in my comment: http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/a/aa042103a.htm

Comment: Ok, I am starting to wrap my head around CSS, however I am still stuck on how to take a saved .HTML file from my local computer, and edit it with CSS in C#

Comment: I try not to ask why someone wants to do this, but I've got to in this case.  What is the purpose of this application?

Comment: I need a 1 page formatted output ( printed ) for reports. I cannot condense the HTML file any farther from the where the file is being generated. I really don't even need to re format the file, just need to fit it to one page. Looking into zoom options right now, seems a bit more straight forward.

Comment: Do you have access to change the code that generates the HTML file?  How are you rendering the HTML?  In both of these cases I still think changing CSS, rendering it to IE (or Firefox or Chrome), and printing from there will be orders of magnitude easier than any other choice.

Comment: Unfortunatley I do not have access to the code that generates the HTML file. I am handed an HTML file and have to deal with it.

Comment: That tends to be the case--sorry you're stuck like that.  My only other suggestion is if it's strictly tabular HTML (like table, tr, tr), you could use C# to spin up an instance of Excel, shoot your HTML over, Excel will interpret the HTML tables and render it nicely, then you could figure out a way to shrink everything so it fits on one Excel-printed page.  I've done everything but the shrinking part, so I know it works.

Comment: I finally got a hold of the engineer in charge of the HTML file generation and it turns out they forgot to give me the directory with the accompanied CSS file. Now its a quick edit and the file is printable. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Garrison Neely suggested the correct answer in my beliefs, just posting some links here:

```
  @media print {
    body { font-size: 10pt }
  }
  @media screen {
    body { font-size: 13px }
  }
  @media screen, print {
    body { line-height: 1.2 }
  }
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/